# Image Augmentation or incrementing dataset by flipping/mirroring?

Tags: deep-learning, image-processing, data-preprocessing, data-augmentation

My task is a regression task, where an input image results in another, transformed image. So far so good, works quite well.

As my data set is fairly small, I want to take some actions. Here I wanted to apply data augmentation by flipping and mirroring the data. This I did for every image and added it to my training set. I got really some satisfying results. See the results:

[image]

But I guess that is not the correct way to do that? After all the data set increases and more space is needed.

Keras `ImageDataGenerator`, as far as I understood, does not increment the size of the data set, it randomly performs those operations to the samples when fetching the mini-batches.

Does the `ImageDataGenerator` approach has an influence on the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did uses more disk space, but runs faster (the augmentation is not calculated again each time). Otherwise the two approaches should be essentially equivalent, if you shuffle your batches.

The reason why a generator is so interesting is that sometimes you have an essentially infinite number of possible augmentation (e.g. rotation by any random angle) and cannot generate all possible augmentations up front.